# SQL/PHP calculate percent of yes/no votes

Tags: php, sql, vote

This has me stumped I have Googled for ages now and have searched here but have had no joy on what is probably a very simple to do ...I dont know maybe im just searching with the wrong search terms i really dont know but heres my question ...

I have a basic voting script click yes vote goes up by 1, click no vote goes up by 1

**SQL Table:**

- **votes**

  - id
  - item
  - yes
  - no

what i want to do is show the percent of wins (yes votes) over loses (no votes) rather then the actual number of votes so on the page rather then it saying

"Wins 400 loses 600"

it will calculate the percent between the yes and no and say:

"Wins 40% loses 60%"

as always thanks in advance for any help and assistance.

**Update:**

How can i get it to show at the moment i'm gettng "id #8 resource"

```
$query  = "SELECT ((yes / (yes+no)) * 100) as yesPercent, ((no / (yes+no)) * 100) as noPercent FROM table WHERE id=1";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo $result;
```

I assume its this line i got wrong (or probably the whole query *novice at work)

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

but have tried a few mysql_????() and none seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it your table would hold

```
id - item - yes   - no
1  - name - 400  - 600
```

Then you'd query

```
SELECT ((yes / (yes+no)) * 100) as yesPercent, ((no / (yes+no)) * 100) as noPercent FROM table WHERE id=1
```

Comment: I would recommend to obtain the proportion from SQL instead the percent, and then to show it in your view by multiplying it by 100...

Comment: Why? As we are talking about very small amounts of performance difference you won't see any effect, but there might be a difference in theoretical performance. I have no clue what would be quicker, so I'm curious as to why this remark?

Comment: I didn't mentioned that because a relevant performance increase, but because I consider that percent is a "presentation" aspect, and getting the proportion would be more usable, i.e. building a graph...

Comment: If you would be building a graph yes, but you could also get the proportion AND the percentage in a query without any negative sides I can think of. SO if you need the proportion, just add it. Don't see why you would leave the caclulation specifically outside the query. You can ofcourse, no argument there!

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple indeed.

You want to use this simple proportion

NumberYes : TotalVotes = Percentage : 100

And you can find percentage using the formula

Percentage = (NumberYes * 100) / TotalVotes